# Using RGB values control individual data points matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

I'm trying to be able to control the colour of an individual data point using a corresponding rgb tuple. I've tried looping through the data set and plotting individual data points however I get the same effect as the code I have below; all that happens is it refuses to produce a graph.

This is an example of the data type I'm working with

Any tips?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y=[(0.200,0.1100,0.520)]

for i in range(4):
    y.append(y)

plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [3,4,5,2],c=y)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Your question is highly unclear. What do you want to achieve. You are appending the same list to itself. You have a single rgb tuple and so why would you expect different colors for each point? You need to first append the correct thing. Try the suggestion in my answer below

Comment: In the actual data the tuple will be different for each time it's appended onto the list, thus every point will have a dynamically controlled colour. this was just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you are appending the list to the new list. Instead, try appending the tuple to the list. Moreover, you need to use `scatter` plot for the color argument which contains rgb tuple for each point. However, in oyur case, I see only a single color for all the scatter points.

```
tup=(0.200,0.1100,0.520)
y = []
for i in range(4):
    y.append(tup)

plt.scatter([1,2,3,4], [3,4,5,2], c=y)
```

A rather short version to your code is using a list comprehension

```
tup=(0.200,0.1100,0.520)
y = [tup for _ in range(4)]
plt.scatter([1,2,3,4], [3,4,5,2], c=y)
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I was after. In actuality the tuple dynamic so I'll have different colour. Thank you